# Comparing if two Date instances refer to the same day

Tags: java, datetime

I have two Java instances of java.util.Date and I have to find out if they refer to the same day.

I can do this the hard way, taking the dates apart and compare the days, making sure the years match too.

Since this is such a common problem, I expect there to be an easier solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instances of `java.util.Date` refer to *instants* in time. Which day they fall on depends on which time zone you're using. You could use a `java.util.Calendar` to represent an instant in a particular time zone...

... or you could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead, which is a much, much better API. Either way, you'll have to know what time zone you're interested in.

In Joda Time, once you've got a relevant time zone, you can convert both instants to `LocalDate` objects and compare those. (That also means you can compare whether instant X in time zone A is on the same day as instant Y in time zone B, should you wish to...)

Answer (score 2):

I use the DateUtils class by [Apache Commons Lang 2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html), it provides the isSameDay(Date,Date) method.

## Update:

Here the link to [Apache Commons Lang 3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html).

Comment: If that's the signature and there's no time zone context anywhere else, then it is necessarily broken (or at least restricted to work in an assumed time zone).

Comment: (The fact that the Javadocs don't even mention which zone is used would make me highly nervous about using that class at all, to be honest. Joda Time is simply a better choice, IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

From [elsewhen on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2517954/2175856)

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
return fmt.format(date1).equals(fmt.format(date2));
```