# java - how to compare same days in date

Tags: java, date

I have a long data member that represents a date.
I cast it to a

```
 Date d = new Date(long);
```

I want to now if a nother date has the same day. 
How do I do it? 
Thanks.
     (For andrew)

Edit :

Found this solution

```
 SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
 return fmt.format(date1).equals(fmt.format(date2));
```

in here
[Comparing two java.util.Dates to see if they are in the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/java-comparing-two-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day)
looks nice

Comment: this answer will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2517954/2939690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the joda api.
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/
Its a lot easier and better than the Calendar object route in java jdk

Answer (score 3):

Well you can convert them both to [calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) Objects and get the calendar objects day and compare that way.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(LONG VALUE HERE);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Do the same thing with the other date, and compare the values.

edit: By the way, you are not casting the long to a date, you are just creating a Date object using a long.

Comment: I think instead of Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH  we should check Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR   because 15 of jun and 15 of july would be same so day of year is right one 

check -https://stackoverflow.com/a/2517824/4741746

Answer (score 2):

Use apache commons.

```
 DateUtils.isSameDay(date1, date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if the dates are equal:

```
date_one.equals(date_two);
```

To see if just the day is equal, I usually chop the time off the date (setHours(0), setMinutes(0), etc.) and then use the `.equals()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use **java.util.Calendar** for all comparison operations.