# How to know if a Date is within the same day of other date

Tags: java, android

If I have a two Dates in Java (Android) (Date1 and Date2), how can I know if the Date2 is within the same day of the Date1? (Note: not if the Date2-Date1 < 24 hours). Some examples (suppousing same month and year)

```
 Date1: day=14 hour=00:00           Date2: day=14 hour=00:00    --> Result TRUE
 Date1: day=13 hour=23:59           Date2: day=14 hour=00:00    --> Result FALSE
 Date1: day=14 hour=05:00           Date2: day=14 hour=00:00    --> Result TRUE
 Date1: day=14 hour=00:00           Date2: day=15 hour=00:00    --> Result FALSE
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your second example also return true?

Comment: I'm guessing `Date2: day=15...` is intended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you use `DateUtils`?

You can directly invoke methods like isSameDay

```
if (DateUtils.isSameDay(date1, date2)) {
    System.out.println("Same Date");
} else if (date1.before(date2)) {
    System.out.println("date1 before date2");
} else {
    System.out.println("date1 after date2");
}
```

Check [Apache DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html).

Comment: Not that this solution doesn't respect the timezone

Answer (score 4):

I copied this from [Java: comparing two Dates to see if they are in the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/java-comparing-two-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day)

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);
boolean sameDay = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                  cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```