# Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

What is the best way to convert a `java.util.Date` object to the new JDK 8/JSR-310 `java.time.LocalDate`?

```
Date input = new Date();
LocalDate date = ???
```

Answer (score 983, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
Date input = new Date();
LocalDate date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

**Explanation**

Despite its name, `java.util.Date` represents an instant on the time-line, not a "date". The actual data stored within the object is a `long` count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z (midnight at the start of 1970 GMT/UTC).

The equivalent class to `java.util.Date` in JSR-310 is `Instant`, thus there is a convenient method `toInstant()` to provide the conversion:

```
Date input = new Date();
Instant instant = input.toInstant();
```

A `java.util.Date` instance has no concept of time-zone. This might seem strange if you call `toString()` on a `java.util.Date`, because the `toString` is relative to a time-zone. However that method actually uses Java's default time-zone on the fly to provide the string. The time-zone is not part of the actual state of `java.util.Date`.

An `Instant` also does not contain any information about the time-zone. Thus, to convert from an `Instant` to a local date it is necessary to specify a time-zone. This might be the default zone - `ZoneId.systemDefault()` - or it might be a time-zone that your application controls, such as a time-zone from user preferences. Use the `atZone()` method to apply the time-zone:

```
Date input = new Date();
Instant instant = input.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

A `ZonedDateTime` contains state consisting of the local date and time, time-zone and the offset from GMT/UTC. As such the date - `LocalDate` - can be easily extracted using `toLocalDate()`:

```
Date input = new Date();
Instant instant = input.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate date = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

**Java 9 answer**

In Java SE 9, a [new method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) has been added that slightly simplifies this task:

```
Date input = new Date();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofInstant(input.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

This new alternative is more direct, creating less garbage, and thus should perform better.

Comment: I had `LocalDate.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()))` I think it's equivalent to yours, but more direct.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that compiles but does not run. An Instant does not contain a time-zone thus there is no way to get the LocalDate.

Comment: @assylias I don't understand your 2nd statement.

Comment: I have just compiled and run it, and it works. Using ThreeTen implementation.

Comment: @JodaStephen How about the method used in java.sql.Date: `return LocalDate.of(getYear() + 1900, getMonth() + 1, getDate())`?

Comment: To confirm, I have also run it against Java 8 and there it fails. So apparently the ThreeTen implementation diverges from Java 8.

Comment: @assylias Just use sqlDate.toLocalDate() !

Comment: @JodaStephen There is some confusion here because both assylias and I were struggling to make this work on Java 7 + ThreeTen. Of course, you can't count on any instance methods of `java.*l.Date`. assylias extracted the source code from Java 8 `java.sql.Date#toLocalDate()` and I drilled a route through the ThreeTen API, which turns out not to be compatible with Java 8.

Comment: The kind of quality (posts) this guy produces is incredible! Would +10 if I could

Comment: @JodaStephen `Date` has no concept of time-zone, `Instant` also does not contain information about time-zone. The `LocalDate` API says "A date without a time-zone". Then why converting from `Date` to `Instant` to `LocalDate` needs `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`?

Comment: @Gustavo: `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` do not "store or represent a time or time-zone" (ref: javadocs).  While they don't store it- the classes do represent a *`Local`* date and/or time, hence the conversion to *local* date/time implies a timezone.

Comment: @avalancha well, he does have a slight advantage in respect of the `java.time`, being the primary author of JodaTime, and a member of the JSR 310 expert group :-)   He's thought more deeply about this problem domain than you or I are likely to need to!

Comment: @SnakeDoc - I think you're mistaken... I see no such method in the Oracle documentation of `java.util.Date`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Sorry, I meant for `java.sql.Date`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--

Comment: @Gustavo what date is new `Date(0)`? that depends on the time zone. In Hawaii its `1969-12-31` but in Australia its `1970-01-01`. That is why you need to define a time zone to make a meaningful conversion. So `ZoneId.systemDefault()` may not be correct for you as that is the time zone the system (JVM) has.

Comment: In some input cases `myDate.toInstant()` gives ab Unsupported operation exception: http://i.imgur.com/HEJbpFo.png Therefore Oliv's answer is more correct.

Comment: LocalDate requires APİ 26 but my minSdk is 19. Thus i cannot use LocalDate. Is there a solution or workaround for that ?

Comment: @oiyio did you find a workaround for API < 26?

Answer (score 188):

Better way is:

```
Date date = ...;
Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
```

Advantages of this version:

- works regardless the input is an instance of `java.util.Date` or it's a subclass of `java.sql.Date` (unlike @JodaStephen's way). This is common with JDBC-originated data. `java.sql.Date.toInstant()` always throws an exception.
- it's the same for JDK8 and JDK7 with JSR-310 backport

I personally use an utility class (but it is not backport-compatible):

```
/**
 * Utilities for conversion between the old and new JDK date types 
 * (between {@code java.util.Date} and {@code java.time.*}).
 * 
 * <p>
 * All methods are null-safe.
 */
public class DateConvertUtils {

    /**
     * Calls {@link #asLocalDate(Date, ZoneId)} with the system default time zone.
     */
    public static LocalDate asLocalDate(java.util.Date date) {
        return asLocalDate(date, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    /**
     * Creates {@link LocalDate} from {@code java.util.Date} or it's subclasses. Null-safe.
     */
    public static LocalDate asLocalDate(java.util.Date date, ZoneId zone) {
        if (date == null)
            return null;

        if (date instanceof java.sql.Date)
            return ((java.sql.Date) date).toLocalDate();
        else
            return Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link #asLocalDateTime(Date, ZoneId)} with the system default time zone.
     */
    public static LocalDateTime asLocalDateTime(java.util.Date date) {
        return asLocalDateTime(date, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    /**
     * Creates {@link LocalDateTime} from {@code java.util.Date} or it's subclasses. Null-safe.
     */
    public static LocalDateTime asLocalDateTime(java.util.Date date, ZoneId zone) {
        if (date == null)
            return null;

        if (date instanceof java.sql.Timestamp)
            return ((java.sql.Timestamp) date).toLocalDateTime();
        else
            return Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(zone).toLocalDateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link #asUtilDate(Object, ZoneId)} with the system default time zone.
     */
    public static java.util.Date asUtilDate(Object date) {
        return asUtilDate(date, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@link java.util.Date} from various date objects. Is null-safe. Currently supports:<ul>
     * <li>{@link java.util.Date}
     * <li>{@link java.sql.Date}
     * <li>{@link java.sql.Timestamp}
     * <li>{@link java.time.LocalDate}
     * <li>{@link java.time.LocalDateTime}
     * <li>{@link java.time.ZonedDateTime}
     * <li>{@link java.time.Instant}
     * </ul>
     * 
     * @param zone Time zone, used only if the input object is LocalDate or LocalDateTime.
     * 
     * @return {@link java.util.Date} (exactly this class, not a subclass, such as java.sql.Date)
     */
    public static java.util.Date asUtilDate(Object date, ZoneId zone) {
        if (date == null)
            return null;

        if (date instanceof java.sql.Date || date instanceof java.sql.Timestamp)
            return new java.util.Date(((java.util.Date) date).getTime());
        if (date instanceof java.util.Date)
            return (java.util.Date) date;
        if (date instanceof LocalDate)
            return java.util.Date.from(((LocalDate) date).atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant());
        if (date instanceof LocalDateTime)
            return java.util.Date.from(((LocalDateTime) date).atZone(zone).toInstant());
        if (date instanceof ZonedDateTime)
            return java.util.Date.from(((ZonedDateTime) date).toInstant());
        if (date instanceof Instant)
            return java.util.Date.from((Instant) date);

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't know hot to convert " + date.getClass().getName() + " to java.util.Date");
    }

    /**
     * Creates an {@link Instant} from {@code java.util.Date} or it's subclasses. Null-safe.
     */
    public static Instant asInstant(Date date) {
        if (date == null)
            return null;
        else
            return Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link #asZonedDateTime(Date, ZoneId)} with the system default time zone.
     */
    public static ZonedDateTime asZonedDateTime(Date date) {
        return asZonedDateTime(date, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    /**
     * Creates {@link ZonedDateTime} from {@code java.util.Date} or it's subclasses. Null-safe.
     */
    public static ZonedDateTime asZonedDateTime(Date date, ZoneId zone) {
        if (date == null)
            return null;
        else
            return asInstant(date).atZone(zone);
    }

}
```

The `asLocalDate()` method here is null-safe, uses `toLocalDate()`, if input is `java.sql.Date` (it may be overriden by the JDBC driver to avoid timezone problems or unnecessary calculations), otherwise uses the abovementioned method.

Comment: It is better in comparison to the accepted answer, I explain why. Yes, it is ugly, but that's why wrote `DateConvertUtils`.

Comment: I don't understand why they didn't implement a conversion class in the new API.

Comment: @ceklock, they *did* implement, not a conversion class, but a couple of conversion methods, like `Date.toInstant()`.

Comment: Is there a Kotlin library that packages these as extension functions so that a developer can do the following. Date x = ...; x.asLocalDate();

Comment: @MarkAshworth I don't know of any

Comment: @Oliv Its old but is not a bad practice return a null, can you explain to me why it would be a good decision? or there are some restrictions where you can do it, thanks

Comment: @Jose What's wrong with returning null? If you pass in a null, what would you expect to return? To throw??

Comment: The need for specifying the timezone it's what irks me given that it is said the date is an instance in time, not if a time

Answer (score 26):

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date) );
```

Comment: Here, the `SimpleDateFormat` instance is *confined* to the current thread.  It is *used* in a thread-safe way.  Now, `SimpleDateFormat` is reputed to be 'expensive to instantiate' (on account of all the internal data structures it needs) but you can't **share** one as a 'singleton' (without synchronizing access to it), because *it* is indeed not thread-safe. (A `ThreadLocal` solution can work *if* the code 'polluting' the `Thread` in this was is responsible for the thread's lifecycle ... but that rarely happens). Awkward. Avoiding `SimpleDateFormat` is *the* reason for using `javax.time`.

Comment: This approach has a lot of overhead: the 'expensive' `SimpleDateFormat` (which is thrown away), the intermediate string (which is thrown away), and the cost of parsing.  It's *a* solution, but not recommended.

Comment: @ceklock but then you get the problem that it's no longer thread-safe

Comment: @ceklock the SimpleDateFormat can only process one date at a time, if you use it concurrently, it'll yield mangled results. So yes, it is important. Don't create a single instance of SimpleDateFormat in a global variable.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Java 8, @JodaStephen's answer is obviously the best.  However, if you're working with the [JSR-310 backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), you unfortunately have to do something like this:

```
Date input = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(input);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: Not true, @JodaStephen's answer still works. You just need another way to convert java.util.Date to an Instant. For this you can use org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html

Comment: DateTimeUtils wasn't available when I was using the backport, but you are correct that it is available to anyone using ThreeTen Backport 1.0 or later.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ChristianCiach You are correct. I spelled out what you are saying in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63068341/5772882).

Answer (score 16):

```
LocalDate ld = new java.sql.Date( new java.util.Date().getTime() ).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: And it simplest realization:

      LocalDate.of(getYear() + 1900, getMonth() + 1, getDate())

Comment: The lines that say deprecated though :|

Answer (score 11):

You can convert in one line :

```
public static LocalDate getLocalDateFromDate(Date date){
   return LocalDate.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
}
```

Comment: I get an error like this using this method:

java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 2018-01-31T11:54:27.964Z of type java.time.Instant

Comment: @LuigiRubino thanks for pointing out. Please see the updated answer. I forgot to add Zone earlier.

Answer (score 9):

first, it's easy to convert a Date to an Instant

```
Instant timestamp = new Date().toInstant();
```

Then, you can convert the Instant to any date api in jdk 8 using ofInstant() method:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: includes localDate, localDateTime, localTime

Comment: What does it mean to specify ZoneId here. If I get Date -> Instant from API and I can think about it as milliseconds from 1970  in UTC. When I want to get just corresponding LocalDate (yyyy-mm-dd) from perspective of api not converted to any timezone, shouldn't I use ZoneOffset.UTC to not have this instant offset to my local timezone. Isn't your example with ZoneId.systemDefault() is shifting date form server. Ex. instant represents 2018-10-20 0:00 and then shifted from UTC to America/Los_Angeles I get in Local Date 2018-10-19 instead of 2018-10-20?

Comment: It breaks if you happen to have `import java.sql.Date` in your file: the `toInstant()` method of `java.sql.Date` always throws.

Answer (score 7):

```
Date input = new Date();
LocalDateTime  conv=LocalDateTime.ofInstant(input.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate convDate=conv.toLocalDate();
```

The `Date` instance does contain time too along with the date while `LocalDate` doesn't. So you can firstly convert it into `LocalDateTime` using its method `ofInstant()` then if you want it without *time* then convert the instance into `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 7):

To simplify the process of converting LocalDate/time to Date and vice versa, I created two charts:

1. converting LocalDate to Date and vice versa:

[image]

2. converting LocalDateTime to Date and vice versa:

[image]

Comment: wrong, `java.util.date` does not have any *timezone*; it's just the current timezone which is used when formatting or calling *toString()*...

Comment: Incorrect: `java.sql.Timestamp` is replaced by `java.time.OffsetDateTime` in JDBC, definitely *not* `LocalDateTime` which discards the valuable info of offset/zone. Likewise, going from `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` makes no sense as you are discarding valuable time zone info with nothing gained in return.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static LocalDate Date2LocalDate(Date date) {
        return LocalDate.parse(date.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"))
```

this format is from `Date#tostring`

```
    public String toString() {
        // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
        int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
        if (index == BaseCalendar.SUNDAY) {
            index = 8;
        }
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
        TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
        if (zi != null) {
            sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
        } else {
            sb.append("GMT");
        }
        sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using ThreeTen Backport including ThreeTenABP

```
    Date input = new Date(); // Imagine your Date here
    LocalDate date = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(input)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
```

If you are using the backport of JSR 310, either you haven’t got a `Date.toInstant()` method or it won’t give you the `org.threeten.bp.Instant` that you need for you further conversion. Instead you need to use the `DateTimeUtils` class that comes as part of the backport. The remainder of the conversion is the same, so so is the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with @JodaStephen's implementation on JBoss EAP 6. So, I rewrote the conversion following Oracle's Java Tutorial in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html.

```java
    Date input = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance();
    gregorianCalendar.setTime(input);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = gregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime();
    zonedDateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score -2):

What's wrong with this 1 simple line?

```
new LocalDateTime(new Date().getTime()).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: Java complains that it cannot invoke toLocalDate() on the primitive type long.  I used an actual Date object; perhaps there's the rub??

Answer (score -8):

I solved this question with solution below

```
  import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
  Date myDate = new Date();
  LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.fromDateFields(myDate);
  System.out.println("My date using Date" Nov 18 11:23:33 BRST 2016);
  System.out.println("My date using joda.time LocalTime" 2016-11-18);
```

In this case localDate print your date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: The question is looking for a  solution using the `java.time` classes in JDK8, not with Joda Time.