# How to set java.time.LocalDate using (the value of) an java.util.Date?

Tags: java, datepicker, java-8, java-time

I use the Java 8 DatePicker (and I like it).

This Class uses `java.time.LocalDate`. 
`Persistence` on the other hand uses (exclusively in MAR 2014) `java.util.Date`.
`LocalDate2Date` is involved but doable (see below) 
but I can't find a way to do Date2LocalDate.

```
....
entityClassFromDatabase.setDate2b(LocalDate2Date(datepicker.getvalue()));
....
}

private java.util.Date LocalDate2Date(LocalDate localDate) {
    [validation code omitted]
    ChronoLocalDateTime cldt = localDate.atStartofDay();
    Instant instant = cldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.from(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
    return Date.from.(instant);
}
```

What I need is something like;

```
datepicker.setvalue(Date2LocalDate(entityClassFromDatabase.getDate2b());
```

I have seen answers that suggest 
   new LocalDate(date);
and variants, but these do not work;

Latest effort was 'conversion' `via java.time.Instant` but although the 'instant' used in `LocalDate2Date` prints out identical to the instant used below:

```
Instant instant = entityClassFromDatabase.getDate2b.toinstant();
LocalDateTime xx = LocalDateTime.from(instant);
```

throws exception below:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2014-03-27T23:00:00Z of type java.time.Instant
```

I'm lost

Comment: if you look for conversion from java.util.Date to LocalDate then look at this [SO-item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate).

Comment: Please learn Java naming conventions (methods should always start with a lower-case letter).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
public LocalDate dateToLocalDate(final Date date)
{
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate();
}
```

However, as mentioned, this has no timezone information anymore.

The javadoc says about this method:

> Obtains an instance of LocalDateTime from an Instant and zone ID.
>
> This creates a local date-time based on the specified instant. First, the offset from UTC/Greenwich is obtained using the zone ID and instant, which is simple as there is only one valid offset for each instant. Then, the instant and offset are used to calculate the local date-time.

Comment: I think OP wants the reverse conversion, or have I misread anything?

Comment: Well, OP says "LocalDate2Date is involved but doable (see below) but I can't find a way to do Date2LocalDate."

Comment: Ok, then my reading error, in English I am not so much on safe ground, sorry. Will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in your timezone as -

`LocalDateTime  localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));`