# How to convert a LocalDate to an Instant?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I work with the new DateTime API of Java 8.

How to convert a LocalDate to an Instant?
I get an exception with

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 2);
Instant instant = Instant.from(date);
```

and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because a `LocalDate` doesn't include a time.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The `Instant` class represents an instantaneous point on the time-line. Conversion to and from a `LocalDate` requires a time-zone. Unlike some other date and time libraries, JSR-310 will not select the time-zone for you automatically, so you must provide it.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
Instant instant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

This example uses the default time-zone of the JVM - `ZoneId.systemDefault()` - to perform the conversion. See here for a [longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/38896) to a related question.

---

Update: The accepted answer uses `LocalDateTime::toInstant(ZoneOffset)` which only accepts `ZoneOffset`. This answer uses `LocalDate::atStartOfDay(ZoneId)` which accepts any `ZoneId`. As such, this answer is generally more useful (and probably should be the accepted one).

PS. I was the main author of the API

Comment: I think this is the more useful than the accepted answer since ZoneId (timezone) is the parameter and not ZoneOffset (hours shifted from UTC, which may change for a timezone in summer/winter).

Comment: In a unit test I am writing, I have a LocalDate, that is converted to a com.google.protobuf.Timestamp and then mapped back to a LocalDate via an Instant, both ways. 

When using the approach the accepted answer suggests, I get the expected LocalDate in return, but using this approach gives me "yesterday" back instead of "today".
My timezone is GMT+1

Answer (score 182):

In order to convert it to an instant you need to have a LocalDateTime instance, e.g.:

```
LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now that I need to specify a time zone to get an Instant.

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: this is good for UTC, but not for local time zones as the offset might change depending on the local date (if it is in summer or winter time)

Answer (score 0):

Using this I'm able to get the local datetime Instance:

```
LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Comment: your answer is about `LocalDateTime`, not `LocalDate`