# How to create Java time instant from pattern?

Tags: java, java-time

Consider a code:

```
TemporalAccessor date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("9999-12-31");
Instant.from(date);
```

The last line throws an exception:

```
Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 9999-12-31 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

How to create `Instant` from `yyyy-MM-dd` pattern?

Comment: First I would try a year lower then 9999 ;D for example try it with 2016.

Comment: Use LocalDate.parse(), transform it to LocalDateTime by choosing a time (atStartOfDay?), transform it to a ZonedDateTime by choosing a time zone (does the date represent an instant in France? In the UK? in Japan?), then transform the ZonedDateTime to an Instant.

Comment: An instant is, well, an instant. 31-12-9999 is a date but not an instant. So you can either parse it to a LocalDate if a date is all you need, or you will have to specify the missing bits (a time + a zone offset or time zone).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215299/how-to-convert-a-localdate-to-an-instant

Answer (score 93):

The string "9999-12-31" only contains information about a date. It does not contain any information about the time-of-day or offset. As such, there is insufficient information to create an `Instant`. (Other date and time libraries are more lenient, but `java.time` avoids defaulting these values)

Your first choice is to use a `LocalDate` instead of an `Instant:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("9999-12-31");
```

Your second choice is to post process the date to convert it to an instant, which requires a time-zone, here chosen to be Paris:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("9999-12-31");
Instant instant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toInstant();
```

Your third choice is to add the time-zone to the formatter, and default the time-of-day:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter FMT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
Instant instant = FMT.parse("9999-31-12", Instant::from);
```

(If this doesn't work, ensure you have the latest JDK 8 release as a bug was fixed in this area).

It is worth noting that none of these possibilities use `TemporalAccessor` directly, because that type is a low-level framework interface, not one for most application developers to use.

Comment: Contrary to what you've shown the [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method of `java.util.Instant` does not take a `DateTimeFormatter`. Instead you have to do `FMT.parse("9999-31-12", Instant::from)`. As the author could you explain why `Instant` is different to the other classes, e.g. `LocalDateTime`, in this respect?

Comment: Originally, `Instant` did not work with `DateTimeFormatter` at all. This was changed during development, but the method you refer to was not added. That said, because many formatters don't work with `Instant`, there is a case to say that adding such a method would be adding something that would often fail, and annoy users.

Comment: Thank you!  This answer helped me get my Java code to parse ISO 8601 timestamps with no minutes field, ie "2019-06-11T08:00Z" :   

`Instant.from((new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH':'mm'Z'").parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0).parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0).toFormatter().withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))).parse(string));`

Answer (score 25):

The problem isn't the fact that you are using the year 9999.  The `Instant.MAX` field evaluates to the timestamp `1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z`, so 9999 as a year is fine.

Dealing with `TemporalAccessors` instead of the more semantically rich types like `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` is like using a `Map` to model an object and its properties instead of writing a `class` -- you have to assure that the value has the fields (like seconds, nanoseconds, etc) that are expected by something receiving it, rather than depending on formally declared operations in a higher level class to prevent dependencies from going unmet.

In your case it is likely that the temporal accessor contained the parsed date fields it was given, but didn't have a "seconds" field that the `Instant` needed. It is best to use the more semantically rich types like `LocalDateTime` in most instances.

Since you only have date fields, you should parse it as a date, then add the time fields before converting it to an Instant. Here is one way, using LocalDate to parse the date:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2016-04-17");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay();
Instant instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you are only interested in the date itself (31st of December 9999), in which case the appropriate type would be a `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("9999-12-31");
```

Or you do want an `Instant`, in which case you need to set a time and time zone, for example, `00:00` in Tokyo:

```
Instant instant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo")).toInstant();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2016-12-31").toInstant());
}
```

the above code gives the following output:

> **2016-12-31T00:00:00Z**

i have answered this question using features('toInstant' method) of java 8. hope this answers your question...

Comment: That code sets a lot of things arbitrarily (and mixes the legacy Date API with the new Java time API)...

Comment: @assylias yes the 'toInstant()' method is available only in the latest version of java. will mention in my answer.

Comment: @downvoter could you care to explain yourself. may i know the reason for the down vote. it would help me improve my answer.

Comment: I think the reason for the downvote is what I said above: (i) you are unnecessarily mixing API, which is confusing and (ii) the output of your example depends on the user time zone (if you are in Hawaii, it will print `2016-12-31T10:00:00Z` for example).

Comment: Depends on the user time zone