# How can I create Hashmap<String,Int : String,String : String,String> in Kotlin for sorting

Tags: sorting, kotlin, hashmap

I know this character (:) is meaningless in my statement, but I wanted to explain what I want. I want to sort a lot of hashmaps adding `Arraylist` and using `sortedBy` but I cant because my values return strings.

Here is my code:

```
newReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                chatMessages.clear()

                for(ds in p0.child(playerIDmatchWhoIs).children){

                    var hashMap = ds.getValue() as HashMap<String, String>
                    var datetime = hashMap.get("datetime").toString()
                    var usermail = hashMap.get("usermail")
                    var usermessage = hashMap.get("usermessage")

                    chatMessages.add("${usermail}: ${usermessage}")
                    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
            }
        })
```

(I want to sort this hashMap, it has `datetime` value but is returning string.)

```
println(hashMap): I/System.out: {datetime=1574807563747, usermessage=jmjgmhg, usermail=1@gmail.com}
```

Comment: Your aim is to sort the `chatMessages`-list by date and time, right?

Comment: yes, it is right.

Comment: What is the type of `hashMap.get("datetime")` (without the call to `toString()`)?

Comment: String, i add that for mismatch (String?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `chatMessages` is of type `List<String>`. This is generally bad because you cannot to anything with strings. I would suggest you to create a `data class` which contains all information about a chat message, like so:

```
data class ChatMessage(val dateTime: Int, val userMail: String?, val userMessage: String?) : Comparable<ChatMessage> {
    override fun compareTo(other: ChatMessage) = this.dateTime.compareTo(other.dateTime)
}
```

As you can see, this class implements the `Comparable<ChatMessage>` interface. If you then define the `chatMessages` list like so

```
private val chatMessages = mutableListOf<ChatMessage>()
```

you can call `chatMessages.sort()` which will then sort the list according to `dateTime` (see the implementation of `compareTo` in `ChatMessage`). The final code would look like that:

```
data class ChatMessage(val dateTime:Int?, val userMail: String?, val userMessage: String?) : Comparable<ChatMessage> {
    override fun compareTo(other: ChatMessage) = this.dateTime.compareTo(other.dateTime)
}

private val chatMessages = mutableListOf<ChatMessage>()

fun yourCode() {
    newReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        /* Use proper variable naming. Nobody will understand, what p0 is, but if you name
        it dataSnapshot, everyone knows at a glance. */
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            chatMessages.clear()

            // Again, what is ds exactly? Name it properly.
            for (ds in dataSnapshot.child(playerIDmatchWhoIs).children) {
                // Kotlin recommends to use val instead of var.
                // This way, you know that your variables cannot be modified unless you want them to be modified.
                val hashMap = ds.getValue() as HashMap<String, String>

                // use indexing instead of the get() method
                val dateTime = hashMap["datetime"]
                val userMail = hashMap["usermail"]
                val userMessage = hashMap["usermessage"]

                // TODO: Handle null values properly
                chatMessages.add(ChatMessage(dateTime!!.toInt(), userMail, userMessage))
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

            chatMessages.sort()
        }
    })
}
```

This assumes that you want to store your timestamp as an integer. However, I would rather recommend to use a time library like `java.time` (built into java). In that case, you can use `java.time.Instant` which has many more possibilities to handle time and all the difficulties to handle time.

Read more about `java.time.Instant` in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Instant). If you want to learn how to parse a `String` to `java.time.Instant`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672012/how-to-create-java-time-instant-from-pattern) might be interesting.

Comment: `sort` relies on your implementation of the `compareTo` method. How are you storing your timestamp?

Comment: you are right, problem was timestamp storing class. I took care of problem. Thanks.