# Check if two instances of "Instant" are on the same date in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I have two instances of the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class from `java.time` such as this:

```
Instant instant1 = Instant.now();
Instant instant2 = Instant.now().plus(5, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

Now I would like to check if the two instances of `Instant` are actually on the same date (day, month and year match). Easy I thought, let's just use the shiny new [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and the universal [`from`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-) static method:

```
LocalDate localdate1 = LocalDate.from(instant1);
LocalDate localdate2 = LocalDate.from(instant2);

if (localdate1.equals(localdate2)) {
   // All the awesome
}
```

Except that universal `from` method is not so universal and Java complains at runtime with an exception:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 2014-11-04T18:18:12Z of type java.time.Instant
```

Which leaves me back at square 1.

What is the recommended/fastest way check if two instances of `Instant` actually have the same date (have the same day, month, and year)?

Comment: In other words, you need something that works with Java 7?  What about Java 6 or Java 5?  How far back do you need this to work?

Comment: This only has to work for Java 8 in my case, should have probably specified that

Comment: How about using `instant1.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)`? Do the same on instant2 and compare the truncated instances?

Comment: Just guessing here, but as you're trying to get a **Local**Date and that Instant doesn't seem to have any location or timezone information...

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/451518) explains how to convert `Instant` to `LocalDate`. `LocalDate.from` doesn't work because `Instant` doesn't include timezone.

Comment: @defaultlocale: Great, this helps! Now the question remains is this the fastest way (but I'll take it for now) :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The Instant class does not work with human units of time, such as
>   years, months, or days. If you want to perform calculations in those
>   units, you can convert an Instant to another class, such as
>   LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime, by binding the Instant with a time
>   zone. You can then access the value in the desired units.
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html

Therefore I suggest the following code:

```
LocalDate ld1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant1, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate ld2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant2, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

if (ld1.isEqual(ld2)) {
    System.out.println("blubb");
}
```

Alternatively you could use

```
instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: if (ld2.getDayOfYear() - ld1.getDayOfYear() == 0) {}