# How to getHourOfDay from a timestamp using java.time?

Tags: java-8, java-time

From a java.util.Date( a timestamp), how can I get the hour of day?

In joda.time I use getHourOfDay().

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions for this. If you wish to use the Java 8 classes from `java.time` the following you need to covert a `Date` to one of the *DateTime* classes. The following can be used to convert a `Date` to a `ZonedDateTime` where you then can get the hour:

```
Date date = new Date();

// Convert to java 8 ZonedDateTime
Date date = new Date();
final ZonedDateTime dateTime = date.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

// Get the hour
int hour = dateTime.getHour();
```

Quite verbose as you have noticed but the simple reason for this is that a `Date` is [sort of an Instant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate)

> Despite its name, `java.util.Date` represents an instant on the time-line, not a "date". The actual data stored within the object is a long count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z (midnight at the start of 1970 GMT/UTC).

Another approach is simply to get the field from a `Calendar` instance.

```
final Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
instance.setTime(date);
final int hourOfDay = instance.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: You convert `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`, but `getHour()` is also available on `ZonedDateTime`, so the extra conversion is unnecessary.