# How to convert from Date to LocalDate when using ThreeTenABP?

Tags: java, android, threetenbp

NOTE: This is answered already excellently in the JDK world [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate), but the accepted answer doesn't apply to the [Android port of JSR-310](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which doesn't have that extended API for Date.

So, what is the best way to convert a `java.util.Date` to `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`?

```
Date input = new Date();
LocalDate date = ???
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should do it (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27378709/286419).

```
Date dateJavaFormat = new Date();
LocalDate dateThreeTenFormat = Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateJavaFormat.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: Thank you. Dates complexity on android is ever puzzling.