# Storing a date with LocalDate

Tags: java, date

I am trying to store a previous date in a LocalDate object, but I am not sure how. 
I have been using my own class until now, but I would like to apply the java.time.LocalDate library. 
Help?

My code: 
    LocalDate theDate = new LocalDate(theYear, theMonth, theDay);

Error message: 
    LocalDate theDate = new LocalDate(theYear, theMonth, theDay);

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: What do you mean by "date"?  `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Are you looking for this?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate

Comment: Something wrong with the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

The Java 8 [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class has no public constructors,

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int theYear=2016;
        int theMonth=1;
        int theDay=21;
        LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.of(theYear,theMonth,theDay);
        System.out.println(theDate);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
LocalDate yesterday = tomorrow.minusDays(2);
```

Comment: LocalDate theDate = new LocalDate(?);

This is how far I have come. The questionmark represents my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I am looking for a way to enter an arbitrary date (yyyy-mm-dd) with the scanner.

Comment: @Erik If you look at the javadoc for [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), you'll find [`LocalDate.parse(String text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). I know, reading the doc is controversial, but you should try it.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do: 
LocalDate theDate = new LocalDate(int theYear, int theMonth, int theDay);

Error message: 
The constructor LocalDate(int, int, int) is not visible