# How to use multiple declarations in lambda filter?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am pretty new to Lambdas and I'm trying to use it the following way, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have multiple declarations where *ONE* of those is the condition?

```
ArrayList<Message> msgs = new ArrayList<>(ms.values());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

msgs.stream().filter( m -> {
    cal.setTime(m.getCreated());
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year
});
```

I understand that it works like:

```
collection.stream().filter(x -> 1 == x);
```

But since I need to set the `Date` and use it with `Calendar` to get the year, I would have to do this in two declarations.

I know this works:

```
msgs.forEach(m -> {
    cal.setTime(m.getCreated());
    if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) != year) {
        msgs.remove(m);
    }
});
```

But I want to know if it is possible to do it the way I'm trying to, or something relatively similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a value if you use curly braces.  It's expecting a boolean return value.  It just assumes that if there's no braces.

`return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year;`

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to know if it is possible to do it the way I'm trying to, or something relatively similar?

You don't even need to use the old `Calendar` API. Since you are using an old `Date`, you would need to convert it to a Java 8 [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), which has [a simple method to get the year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#getYear--).

Your filter would then look like this (extracted to a method for clarity):

```
List<Message> filterOnYear(int year, List<Message> msgs) {
  return msgs.stream()
      .filter(msg -> msg.getCreated().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getYear() == year)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[`Date#toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) is a new method in Java 8, which we here use as a bridge between the old `Date` and the Java 8 Date and Time API. The conversion might seem a bit tedious, but it is because a `Date` is not exactly a date, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/1421925):

> Despite its name, java.util.Date represents an instant on the time-line, not a "date". The actual data stored within the object is a long count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z (midnight at the start of 1970 GMT/UTC).