# How to compare objects of LocalDate and Calendar class?

Tags: java, localdate, java-calendar

I am trying to compare dates from two object having different types. Is there any way to convert Calendar object to LocalDater or vice-versa?

Thank you :)

```
public class ABC{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Calendar c1= Calendar.getInstance();
        LocalDate c2= LocalDate.now();      
        System.out.println(c1.compareTo(c2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try comparing their year, month and day values?

Comment: What about doing a cast? I'm not sure it will works, since Calendar doesn't extends from LocalDate and viceversa.

Comment: @HessianMad Cast doesn't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compare **dates**, so let's do just that.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/180719) as reference:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

LocalDate calendarAsLocalDate = calendar.toInstant()
    .atZone(calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId())
    .toLocalDate();

return calendarAsLocalDate.compareTo(localDate)
```

Comment: You should replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with `calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId()`, to guarantee the conversion handles every Calendar object correctly.

Comment: @VGR Thank you, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private int compare(Calendar c1, LocalDate c2) {
        int yearCompare = ((Integer) c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)).compareTo(c2.getYear());
        if (yearCompare == 0)
            return ((Integer) c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)).compareTo(c2.getDayOfYear());
        else
            return yearCompare;
    }
```

Comment: You can do comparisons of int values by simply subtracting them.  For instance, `int yearCompare = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c2.getYear();`.  This works even when there is integer overflow, due to the nature of twos-complement representation.