# Convert Calendar to LocalDate

Tags: java, optaplanner

I decided to upgrade from 5.5 to Optaplanner 7.5 Nurseroster but have run into a number of silly issues. Below is one. The routine I previously used is below. Now however the new version requires LocalDate. I have an MySql database back-end and the users select the roster schedule planner via a calendar. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
int shiftDateSize = maxDayIndex + 1;
        List<ShiftDate> shiftDateList = new ArrayList<ShiftDate>(shiftDateSize);
        //shiftDateMap = new HashMap<String, ShiftDate>(shiftDateSize);
        long id = 0L;
        int dayIndex = 0;
        calendar.setTime(startDate);
        for (int i = 0; i < shiftDateSize; i++) {
            ShiftDate shiftDate = new ShiftDate();
            shiftDate.setId(id);
            shiftDate.setDayIndex(dayIndex);
            **String dateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());**
            shiftDate.setDateString(dateString);
            **shiftDate.setDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.valueOfCalendar(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));**
            shiftDate.setShiftList(new ArrayList<Shift>());
            shiftDateList.add(shiftDate);
            shiftDateMap.put(dateString, shiftDate);
            id++;
            dayIndex++;
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        nurseRoster.setShiftDateList(shiftDateList);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate)

Comment: @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class) try it

Answer (score 22):

I have tried the following code to get the **LocalDate** from **Calendar**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = calendar.getTimeZone();
ZoneId zid = tz == null ? ZoneId.systemDefault() : tz.toZoneId();
LocalDate localDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), zid).LocalDate();
```

or simply in one line:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId()).toLocalDate();
```

I have followed these steps from this link [Convert Calendar to LocalDateTime](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java-8-date-time-api/calender-to-localdatetime.html)

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8 you can just do

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(cal.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Answer (score 9):

Java 9

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

LocalDate.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code probably works too.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date input = cal.getTime();
LocalDate da = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

This first gets the date in **Date** type and then converts it to **LocalDate** format as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the LocalDate(Time) from your SQL database and is the only API connection point (so Calendar isn't exposed anywhere), then **don't use Calendar at all**.

Use a Hibernate/JPA or JDBC version that supports LocalDate(Time) and read that directly from the database. They've been supporting it for years, but your hibernate/JPA or JDBC version connecting to MySQL might be older.

It is *error prone* to read a date from the database as a Calendar and then convert the Calendar into a LocalDate(Time). `java.util.Calendar` is inherently broken, that's why LocalDate(Time) was created. IIRC, errors included dependence on OS settings (timezone, DST rules, etc), making it's behavior machine dependent.

If Calendar is exposed in your API, then this answer won't work, of course.

Comment: Since Hibernate supported LocalDate other features regarding java.util.Date are broken. This is not funny: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11875