# How would I convert the exact amount of time (years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds) between two Calendar objects?

Tags: java

I am trying to covert the exact amount of time between two Calendar objects in Java.

This is the code that I currently have...

```
public static Map<TimeUnit, Long> computeDifference(Calendar date1, Calendar date2) { 

    long diffInMillies = date2.getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTimeInMillis();

    //create the list
    List<TimeUnit> units = new ArrayList<TimeUnit>();
    units.add(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    units.add(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    units.add(TimeUnit.HOURS);
    units.add(TimeUnit.DAYS);
    Collections.reverse(units);

    //create the result map of TimeUnit and difference
    Map<TimeUnit,Long> result = new LinkedHashMap<TimeUnit,Long>();
    long milliesRest = diffInMillies;

    for ( TimeUnit unit : units ) {

        //calculate difference in millisecond 
        long diff = unit.convert(milliesRest,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long diffInMilliesForUnit = unit.toMillis(diff);
        milliesRest = milliesRest - diffInMilliesForUnit;

        //put the result in the map
        result.put(unit,diff);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When printed, the output looks like this `{DAYS=1, HOURS=10, MINUTES=30, SECONDS=45}` for input `date1 = 19 August 2019 02:00:00` and `date2 = 20 August 2019 12:30:45`

The largest time unit available in this method is `DAYS`, but I want to find something that includes both months and years.  I realize that TimeUnit doesn't really have anything to do with specific calendar dates (rather a 24-hour interval), which is why I was wondering if there is any way to make this conversion using the Calendar class or something similar.  I've also looked into ChronoUnit as a substitute for TimeUnit, but that won't work for the same reason TimeUnit doesn't.

Would love any suggestions for how to incorporate larger time units.  Thank you!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `Calendar` if you can at all avoid it.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Years and months aren't exact amounts of time.

Comment: @Max Vollmer I know that years and months aren't exact amount of time, that's why an enum like TimeUnit or ChronoUnit won't work.  I'm asking if there is some solution to this using `Calendar` methods.  I read through the entire java doc, just might need a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: @shmosel what do you suggest I use if not `Calendar`?

Comment: Use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library.

Comment: Compare it in nano or milliseconds from the calendar object

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369144/5133585) before trying to represent an amount of time consisting of a year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds. You are essentially trying to combine the functionalities of `Period` and `Duration`, which can lead to many complications.

Comment: If you can use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) this will help [Calculate difference between two LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `Calendar` class, since it's obsolete. You should use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

In order to get the desired result, you could use the `Period` class.

You first need to [convert both `Calendar` instances to `LocalDate` instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983572/convert-calendar-date-to-localdate).

Then you could use `Period.between(startDate, endDate)` to get a `Period` instance, which makes the `getDays()`, `getMonths()` and `getYears()` methods available to you.

---

If you also want to include time components (hours, minutes and seconds), then you could use `Duration` in combination with `Period`. But then first [read the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369144/5133585) linked to by Sweeper.

Something like this would probably work:

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 4, 26, 5, 56, 40);

Duration d = Duration.between(start.toLocalTime(), end.toLocalTime());
Period p = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate());

// If the startdate's time component lies behind the enddate's time component,
// then we need to correct both the Period and Duration
if (d.isNegative()) {
    p = p.minusDays(1);
    d = d.plusDays(1);
}

System.out.printf("y %s m %s d %s h %s m %s s %s%n",
    p.getYears(),
    p.getMonths(),
    p.getDays(),
    d.toHours() % 24,
    d.toMinutes() % 60,
    d.getSeconds() % 60);
```

<sup>Note that Java 9 comes with `to…Part` methods, so you don't have to use the modulo operator anymore.</sup>

---

**Be advised:** this code does not take into account clock adjustments due to daylight savings time.

Comment: The code block makes no sense. `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, so is the wrong type to track elapsed time between moments (the original `Calendar` objects represents moments, specific points on the timeline). So this code ignores anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) that mean days are not always 24-hours long; days can be 23, 25, 23.75, or other numbers of hours long.

Comment: I know, I already mentioned the article linked to by Sweeper in the comments, which warns about this very fact. So if the code block is used in its current form, then the user accepts these anomalies. I'll edit the post to emphasize this even more.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Period
.between(
    ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalStart ).toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() ,
    ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalStop ).toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() 
)
```

…or…

```
Duration
.between(
    ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalStart ).toInstant() ,
    ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalStop ).toInstant() 
)
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Never use `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such. Use only the classes found in the *java.time* packages.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Assuming both your `Calendar` objects are actually [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) objects underneath, convert. To convert, call new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

```
// start
GregorianCalendar gcStart = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalStart ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = gcStart.toZonedDateTime() ;

// stop
GregorianCalendar gcStop = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalStop ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = gcStop.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Both `GregorianCalendar` and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) represent a date with a time-of-day placed in the context of a time zone, combined to determine a moment (a specific point on the timeline). `ZonedDateTime` resolves to a finer level of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

## `Period`

If you care about elapsed time in terms of years-months-days, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) with [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects. `LocalDate` represents a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone. We can extract the date portion from our `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```
LocalDate ldStart = zdtStart.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate ldStop = zdtStop.toLocalDate() ;
Period p = Period.between( ldStart , ldStop ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = p.toString() ;
```

Interrogate for a count of years, months, days.

```
int years = p.getYears() ;
int months = p.getMonths() ;
int days = p.getDays() ;
```

## `Duration`

If you cane about elapsed time in terms of hours-minutes-seconds, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). This class represent a pair of moments in UTC. So we extract `Instant` objects from our pair of `ZonedDateTime` objects, which internally keep a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, plus a fractional second as a count of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instantStart = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant instantStop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;
Duration d = Duration.between( instantStart , instantStop ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

Interrogate for a count of days (as 24-hour chunks of time unrelated to the calendar), hours, minutes, seconds.

```
long days = d.toDaysPart() ;
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart() ;
int nanos = d.toNanosPart() ;
```

## `PeriodDuration`

If you think about it, you will see that it does not make sense to combine years/months/days with 24-hour-days/hours/minutes/seconds. See [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32366154/642706) as food for thought.

But if you insist on combining these two different concepts, see the [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]