# How to get time and date parts separately from an existing java.util.Date object

Tags: java, scala, date, time

I have been trying and trying but I'm pretty surprised as not to be able to find a solution for my simple problem.

I have a date variable which has value like this:

```
res0: java.util.Date = Mon Jul 15 07:50:59 AET 2019
```

now I want only the Date part not the time. the functions available in the Date for such are deprecated. and all the solutions I found were using Calendar instance to get today's datetime and convert it into string using SimpleDateFormat.

I don't want a string. I want a Date without the time part and a time without the date part.

Comment: You can parse the String as a LocalDateTime, which has methods to extract just the date part as a LocalDate, and just the time part as a LocalTime.

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Comment: You really can’t have a `Date` without the time part and one without the date part. A `Date` is always a point in time, nothing more, nothing less. You can of course have a `Date` representing the start of the day in some time zone and another one representing the time of day on the epoch day, Jan 1 1970, in some time zone. It might just be confusing, though. Instead I suggest that you drop the poorly designed `Date` class and use a `LocalDate` for the date and a `LocalTime` for the time of day. That’s exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate
.toInstant()
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" )
) 
.toLocalDate()
```

For time-of-day only, without date and without time zone:

```
.toLocalTime()
```

To generate a string, call:

```
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatSyle.MEDIUM )
    .withLocale( new Locale( "en" , "AU" ) )
)
```

## Details

Immediately convert your `java.util.Date` from its legacy class to the modern replacement, `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Both of those classes represent a moment as seen in UTC, that is, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Adjust into a time zone by which you want to perceive the date.

For any given moment the time-of-day and the date both vary by time zone around the globe. Noon in Paris is not noon in Montréal. And a new day dawns earlier in the east than in the west. You must get very clear on this to do proper date-time handling. One moment in nature can be viewed in many ways through human-created notions of time zones.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `AET`, `EST`, or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" ) ;
```

Apply to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Both represent the same simultaneous moment, but are viewed with a different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Extract the time-of-day portion.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Put them back together again.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

If you need a `java.util.Date` again to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert.

```
Date d = Date.from( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

Comment: nice explanation! thanks a lot. I'm relatively new to Scala/Java world. hence I'm bound to make mistakes :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

```
val input = new Date() // your date
val date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toLocalDate()
```

Here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/2750966

Comment: “AET” is a pseudo-zone. A real time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [date formatter](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/parsing-formatting-dates.html) to turn it into String and parse it back to Date.

For example:

```
Date yourDate = ...;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(yourDate));
```

The new date object now only has the date part, with the time part being filled with zeroes. For a numeric solution with the same result, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147269/3184968). Alternatively, if you don't want the time part at all, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147096/3184968) should suit you better.

Comment: the question is How?.. I'm not an expert of Java world

Comment: I added an example to my answer

Comment: yes but ... I don't get it. you convert the date to string and then again to a date. I mean it gets the job done but feels like a somersault

Comment: It's just one way of doing it. It may be an extra step, but it's a quick solution. As always there are other ways of doing it like stated in the other answers.

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using the date formatter, you can try the following code.

```
object DateFormatter extends App {
  val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, HH:mm:ss:SSS Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
  val date = new Date()
  val nowDate = sdf.format(date)
  println(nowDate)
  // It prints date in this format Monday July 22, 23:40:07:987 +0545 2019

  // Lets print the date in the format you have provided in your question
  val parsedDate = sdf.parse(nowDate)
  println(parsedDate)

  // Now, we have same date format as yours

  // Now we have to remove the time and keep the date part only, for this we can do this
  val newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  val dateOnly = newDateFormat.format(parsedDate)
  println(dateOnly)

  //Printing time only
  val timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
  val timeOnly = timeFormatter.format(parsedDate)
  println(timeOnly)

  }
```

Output:

```
nowDate: Tuesday July 23, 07:08:05:857 +0545 2019
parsedDate: Tue Jul 23 07:08:05 NPT 2019
dateOnly: 2019-07-23
timeOnly: 07:08:05
```

**Update**

```
val dateNotInString = newDateFormat.parse(dateOnly)
  println(dateNotInString)
```

Output of Update:

```
dateNotInString: Tue Jul 23 00:00:00 NPT 2019
```

Here, you can see that `dateNotInString` is a date object and it does not contain any time related info. Similarly, time only info can be extracted.

**Second Update**

We can’t have a Date without the time part and without the date part using the `SimpleDateFormat` with type `not String` but we can convert it into `LocaleDate` and `LocaleTime`.

```
import java.time.Instant

  val instantTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(parsedDate.getTime)

  import java.time.LocalDateTime
  import java.time.LocalTime
  import java.time.ZoneId

  val res = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantTime, ZoneId.systemDefault).toLocalTime
  println("localeTime " + res)

  val res1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(parsedDate.toInstant,ZoneId.systemDefault).toLocalDate
  println("localeDate " + res1)
```

**Output of the second Update**

```
localeTime: 18:11:30.850
localeDate: 2019-07-23
```

It's type is `LocaleTime` and `LocaleDate` respectively now.

Comment: thanks a lot. however I think you missed the last line of the problem _I don't want a string. I want a Date without the time part and a time without the date part._ If you can alter your solution a bit?

Comment: I don't think that is important. Check the second update please.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date date = new Date(res0.getTime() - (res0.getTime() % 86400000));
    System.out.println(date);
```

Now you can use the date formatter as is with your res0 date and it will print the date only. But what I tried to do is remove the time part basically 86400000 is the number of milliseconds per day and getTime return the number of milliseconds passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.  So basically this is equivalent to the date at time 00:00.00 of each day. I don't know if this is what you want because Date doesn't hold 2 separate things like date and time it just has a single long.