# Convert SQL or UTIL DATE to expected format "dd-MMM-yyyy", but not in String value

Tags: java, sql, date

I have a java util Date object and I need to write it in the format "dd-MMM-yyyy", but not as a String ( it can be sql or util Date, it does not matter ) and I do not understand what I am doing wrong because instead of "Nov" for month, I get "11". The right output is given only when I format to String...

Can anyone help me ? This is what I tried so far and the reason I do not want a String is because I need to use this date as a parameter to run a database query and the field type in sql is Date.

```
        Date currentDate = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());  output value: Thu Nov 14 17:21:44 EET 2019
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate);    output value: 14-Nov-2019
        java.util.Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(formattedDate);    output value: Thu Nov 14 00:00:00 EET 2019
        java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); output value: 2019-11-14
```

Comment: `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` objects do not represent formatted dates but simply dates that can be formatted to strings if you apply a format style to them. A *formatted* date is a string.

Comment: A Date is just a long integer, a count of milliseconds since the epoch.  It doesn't "have" any format until you convert it to a string.  It is the default Date.toString() method that is giving you the format with "11" as the month.

Comment: and is there any way I could get that "Nov" instead of "11" ?

Comment: See the ```SimpleDateFormat``` class, which is for formatting a Date into a String.

Comment: The 3d line of your code returns what you expect.

Comment: Is this not other way around to duplicate @sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: @Deadpool Maybe I misunderstood. I'm going off another-dave's comment that clarifies that a Date doesn't have a format. Louis' answer in the duplicate explains that.

Comment: @Deadpool Did you mean this question should be used as a duplicate to close that one?

Comment: sorry, I mean if i understand OP want to convert `util.Date` to `LocalDate` something like this @SotiriosDelimanolis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate But the above duplicate shows how to convert date string to `util.Date`

Comment: @Deadpool Yeah, we can add that, but I think their misunderstanding is about the nature of these date classes, ie. they do not have formats.

Comment: @Maria, given the comments above, please clarify your question.

Comment: You i agree with this `the nature of these date classes, ie. they do not have formats.` @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: I recommend you don’t use any of the `Date` classes, `Calendar` nor `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

The question is confused, you can use a common Date source i.e. Calendar and then use it as you need. If you need to set a parameter I think you should set it via preparedstatement like this:

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date sqlDate=new java.sql.Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
preparedStatement.setDate(1, sqlDate);
```

if you want to see the formatted String you can for sure use it with simpledateformat.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(utilDate);
```