# Java Converting Retrieved TimeStamp to Instant Gives Wrong Day

Tags: java, time, timestamp, java-time, localdate

I've made a simple method which is used to convert a timestamp retrieved from a database into a LocalDate. However for some reason I keep getting the wrong day in the conversion. I've shared the code below.

```
    private LocalDate getLocalDateFromTimeStamp(Row row, String key){
        return LocalDate.parse(row.getTimestamp(key).toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
}
```

So the date I'm expecting is 2022-12-21 but what I get is 2022-12-22.

When I debug and check what

> row.getTimestamp(key)

gets me a `Date` object of `Wed Dec 21 20:47:46 CST 2022` which is what I expect.

When I check what

> row.getTimestamp(key).toInstant()

does, I get "2022-12-22T02:47:46.299Z". And I think this is where the problem is popping up and I'm not sure why it's happening. The LocalDate that's returned by the method is "2022-12-22".

If anyone could shine a light on this I'd really appreciate it as I'm lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: What  type does  `getTimeStamp(key)` return?

Comment: @WJS It returns a Date object.

Comment: Which `Row` class is that? A homegrown one? I find it very confusing that `getTimestamp()` returns a `Date`. Which, BTW, is a poorly designed and long outdated class, so if you can upgrade the class to be able to return a modern type, do. I do realize that for now this would probably just move the cause of your error elsewhere.

Comment: The `Instant` is independent of time zone and is not he problem. What confused you was that it prints in UTC. Your error comes from doing `.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`, which gives you the UTC date, December 22, which you don’t want. Instead you need `return row.getTimestamp(key).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();`. When running in America/Chicago time zone it gives the desired `2022-12-21` (not knowing whether that is your time zone, just given as an example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert java.util.Date to
java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this. Check out [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for details on the following arguments.

```
String date = "Wed Dec 21 20:47:46 CST 2022";
```

- `EEE` three letter day of week
- `MMM` three letter month
- `dd` integer day
- `HH:mm:ss` time using 24 hour clock
- `z` time zone name (CST)
- `yyyy` year

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
LocalDate dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, dtf).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(dt);
```

prints

```
2022-12-21
```

**Updated**

If you actually have an instance of `Date` you might try the following:

```
LocalDate ldt = LocalDate.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), 
    ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! If you have a second could you explain that format to be, the pattern you used to make the DateTimeFormatter? 

Also do you have any idea why the code I had would behave the way it does? I don't get why it would just change the day like that.

Comment: I'm not certain why it added the day unless it was adjusted based on the time zone to a different default local time.

Comment: One of life's mysteries I guess. Could you explain what the "EEE LLL" section in the format means? I'm unfamiliar with it. Or could you point me to a resource where I could learn a bit about it?

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the date is not tied to a specific timezone as it is in this format? Meaning so that it can localize the time in whatever timezone it happens to be in?

Comment: *Or could you point me to a resource where I could learn a bit about it?* The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package replaces the outdated and buggy `Date` and related legacy classes.  The `DateTimeFormatter` documentation is linked in my answer.

Comment: The OP has got an old-fashioned 'Date`. We don’t need to go through `toString()` and parsing again to convert to `LocalDate`. Also `LLL` in the format pattern string is wrong. It needs to be `MMM`. You also need to specify a locale for your formatter (in practice it will probably work if you correct only one of the two errors, but it will be confusing).

Comment: Your updated way is very good. I suggest you either push the bad way to the end of your question or leave it out.

Comment: *M/L for Number/Text* does *not* mean M for number and L for text. M and L both work for both numbers and text. The difference is (quote) *Pattern letters 'L', 'c', and 'q' specify the stand-alone form of the text styles.* While in English the stand-alone form of a month abbreviation should be no different, there are languages where it *is* different. A reader familiar with such a language will be confused about `LLL` with day-of-month.

Comment: @OleV.V. OK.  Thanks for the explanation.  I'll change it to M.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Avoid unnecessary string manipulation. Use date-time types for date-time values.

```
myResultSet
.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )  // For any database column of a data type akin to the SQL standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
.toLocalDate()  // Extract the date portion from the returned `OffsetDateTime` object. 
.toString()     // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## Details

The `Timestamp` class is part of the terrible date-time classes that are now legacy. Use only their replacements, the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Instead of `Timestamp`, use `OffsetDateTime` with JDBC 4.2 and later. Do this for any database column of a data type akin to the SQL standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Your Question is not clear, but you seem to want the date portion of that moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

The retrieved `OffsetDateTime` is likely already in UTC. But let’s be sure:

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate localDate = odtUtc.toLocalDate() ;
```

To generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.

```
String output = localDate.toString() ;
```