# Compare two date and get the result in android

Tags: android, date, compare

First , there is a base date for comparsion

Date baseDate = dateFormat.parse("2013-01-01");

And there is a list of event date to compare with the base date  e.g.
Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("2013-01-02");

So, I would like to get the compare result (in day unit), in this case it is 1.

And if

Date date3 = dateFormat.parse("2012-12-31");

Then , the result should be -1

How can I achieve that? Tried `baseDate .compareTo(date3)` but it only return true/false. Thanks for helping

Comment: What kind of Date is it? java.util.Date? java.sql.Date?

Comment: java.util.Calendar;
java.util.Date; thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/comparing-two-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/comparing-two-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day)

Comment: I would like to get the difference in date unit instead of checking whether two day is the same day . Thanks for your remind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to call `java.util.Date.getTime()` in your `Date` objects, which returns the `Date` as a millisecond value. You can them calculate `(date2.getTime() - baseDate.getTime()) / 24*60*60*1000`.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

Comment: it seems the 24*60*60*1000 can not convert to date,  I check that now, thanks

Comment: If you cast the above equation to `int`, you should have the number of days between the 2 dates. The positive or negative will represent if `date2` was after (positive) or before (negative) the `baseDate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String dateStart = "01/14/2014";
    String dateStop = "01/13/2014";

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Date has a [`compareTo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) function that conforms to the `Comparable` interface. This method returns an integer.