# Get document created between a date in Firestore

Tags: android, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to store the details of users. I have a field *datetime* which is a server timestamp, which denotes the time of user creation. I need to get the users created **today**. Is there any direct way so that I need not to worry about the wrong date/time set in the android device of the user. How should I query users created between a timestamp?

Answer (score 4):

You should query your Cloud Firestore database using a query that should look somethig like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
Query query = usersRef
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", startingTime)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", endingTime);
```

In Cloud Firestore is allowed to chain multiple `where` clauses in a single query.

Comment: thanks for reply, but the real problem here is that i want the users created **today** , and how to get that today????

Comment: When you are using the server timestamp you need to know that is a locale-agnostic and does not require formatting and parsing agreements between clients. So it's better to use this rather than trusting the clients to have their clocks set correctly. So if you want to know users "today", you need to check this client side, not server side.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/comparing-two-java-util-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day) is how you can compare two dates on user side.

Comment: Thanks #alex. Sure please.