# How do you get the day out of a Date object since "getDay()" is deprecated?

Tags: android-studio, date

When the user opens my app the date is recorded. Then it's compared with the last date that was recorded. I want to be able to tell if just the day changed between the 2. And I don't want to simply see if 24 hours lapsed. The user should be able to open the app at 11:59pm, and then again in 2 minutes and the code should tell that the day has changed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that solves my problem (although technically doesn't directly get the day out of the Day object.)

[Comparing two java.util.Dates to see if they are in the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517709/comparing-two-java-util-dates-to-see-if-they-are-in-the-same-day)

Basically make a Calendar object and call it's "setTime()" method with my Date object as the argument, then use ".get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) to get the day from each Calendar object.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, and if you want to get the **actual** day you just need to use Calendar.getInstance() like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```